# Parse text with delimiter line by line

Tags: python, parsing, text

Can somebody shine me some light how you would approach this in python?
I am trying to parse a text file, which contains a list of coordinates

```
XCOORDINATE|YCOORDINATE
XCOORDINATE|YCOORDINATE
XCOORDINATE|YCOORDINATE
...
```

I am trying to parse the coordinates on line 1, then do the same on line2, etc.
I am having trouble dividing each line into "XCOORDINATE" and "YCOORDINATE" parsing it, and moving onto the next line.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: When you ask these kinds of question, always include the code you used, the details and procedure you employed and the error you got with it's traceback. If it's not an error but a wrong output, you should mention a minimal and verifiable example. Also upload your text file. I've answered a similar issue with text files earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to iterate over your file, and use `str.split()` to divide the string to two separate coordinates:

```
with open('full/path/to/file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        # Filter out any whitespace
        line = line.replace(' ', '').strip()

        # Split each line into a list containing two parts. The x coordinate
        # and the y coordinate. Unpack the list into two variables.
        xcoord, ycoord = line.split('|')

        # Use the coordinates here
        print(xcoord)
        print(ycoord)
```

You may also need to convert the two coordinates to integers, in which case you can do:

```
xcoord, ycoord = [int(n) for n in line.split('|')]
```